# django: Models with multiple Foreign Key queries

Tags: django, django-models

I have finished a proof-of-concept django project and now want to redesign the models to be more robust.

The basic model is called a `PhraseRequest`:

```
class PhraseRequest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    phrase = models.TextField()
```

Now the complication comes in that one `PhraseRequest` has a bunch of associated models, `PhraseRequestVote`, `Phrase` (a response), `PhraseRequestComment`&c.

Now when I list say, the top ten Phrase Requests in order of votes, my template has a for-each loop which is fed the ten PhraseRequest objects.  It then populates the HTML with the request, and all it's associated data.

So far I have been adding to each `PhraseRequest`'s dictionary to achieve this:

```
for r in phrase_requests:
    r.votes = PhraseRequestVote.objects.filter(request=r)
    r.n_votes = sum([v.weight for v in r.votes])
    r.comments = PhraseRequestComment.objects.filter(request=r)
    #and so on
```

Intuitively, this doesn't seem right - There must be a "correct" way to do this. Do I need to redesign the models? The query?

Answer (score 1):

You can make function in your model and order it in your view. Like this

models.py

```
class model_name(models.Model)

    ........

    def votes(self):
         return Vote_Name.objects.filter(phrase_id=self).count()
```

Comment: ahh yes!  I could even make this a property right? By overriding the `getattr`